# Is it possible to use .after() and time.sleep() together in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, sleep

I want to keep updating the program after some time(using time.sleep(0.1)) and call a certain function after a delay of every 1 second(using .after()). Is it possible to do that? Below is a part of the code, I just have to add .after() and I don't know where it should go since writing that in the while loop doesn't give the intended result.

```
while True:
    draw()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    win.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `after` and `sleep` together, but they will each do what they are documented to do. `sleep` will cause the program to sleep, and after will run the job sometime after the given time period. If the program is sleeping, it can't process event queues so the jobs scheduled by `after` can't run until the program stops sleeping.

For example, if you do `root.after(1000, something)` followed by `time.sleep(5)`, Then the program will sleep for five seconds, and then when it wakes up it will run `something`.

As a general rule of thumb, you should never call `time.sleep` in the main thread of a GUI program.